# Deluge and aufs mounted drives

Tags: mount, fstab, deluge

I have an issue with Deluge 1.3.6, saving torrents to joint drives by aufs - when one of joint drive is out of space, second one is not used for storage and Deluge stops with error.

I'm joining 2 drives in aufs as follows (in file `rc.local`):

```
mount -t aufs -o br:/media/NAS3=rw:/media/NAS4=rw -o sum -o udba=reval -o create=mfsrr:10000000 none /media/NAS
```

When copying files to the joint drive thru SMB, or in Krusader, aufs looks to be working properly - it shares files between drives, starting from the most empty drive. But when it comes to Deluge, the only initial drive is used.
Tried this with 2, 3 and 4 drives, joint in aufs.

Drives are mounted in `fstab` as following:

NAS3 on `/dev/sdc1`

```
UUID=de8f40ca-94bc-41f7-a93b-9f1a9c0d899a /media/NAS3  ext4  users,exec,dev,suid,rw     0  0
```

NAS4 on `/dev/sdd1`

```
UUID=d1be4e64-cae1-4d2b-9838-3ab5e9b9398f /media/NAS4  ext4  users,exec,dev,suid,rw     0  0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like something to be raised with libtorrent developer, are you using 0.16 libtorrent?

Comment: Deluge says it's libtorrent: 0.16.13.0.

Comment: Just tested with Transmission - result is the same as for Deluge - when capacity of one drive is over, it stops, not using another drive.

Answer (score 0):

A forum user suggests not using round robin [(Source)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2166871)

So change:

```
create=mfsrr:10000000
```

To:

```
create=msf
```

There are other create options in the **manpage**

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't help. Still uses only one drive. Noticed another thing - not the most empty drive is used for writing.